# Error while installing python

Tags: 14.04, python, pip

While installing python 3.4.2 am getting error like Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 1.5.6 requires SSL/TLS on ubuntu 14.04 .slove and give me guys please

Comment: "An error like ..." Not really useful to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Install the `libssl-dev` package from the repository. Run the following command in the terminal:

> `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`